# Find and Replace string within sheet macro using code in another macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet and worksheet related code called "GL Budget2". The code contains several instances of the string "GL Budget". This string must be renamed "GL Budget2" by using code from within another macro called FindAndReplace. My code (thanks to Pearson):

```
Sub FindAndReplace()

    Dim SL As Long, EL As Long, SC As Long, EC As Long
    Dim S As String
    Dim Found As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("GL Budget2").CodeModule
        SL = 1
        SC = 1
        EL = 99999
        EC = 999
        Found = .Find("GL Budget", SL, SC, EL, EC, True, False, False)

        If Found = True Then
            S = .Lines(SL, 1)
            S = Replace(S, "GL Budget", "GL Budget2")
            .ReplaceLine SL, S
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

It crashes with the subscript out of range error on the line

```
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("GL Budget2").CodeModule
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`GL Budget2` is likely not the *code name* of your sheet, but the name on the sheet tab.

Try this:

```
Dim cn as string

cn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GL Budget2").CodeName

With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(cn).CodeModule
'...etc
```

Comment: Tim: GL Budget is the name of the original tab, and GL Budget2 is the name of the copy. GL Budget has event handler code that is exactly copied for GL Budget2, but I need to change the sheet name within the GL Budget2 code from "GL Budget" to "GL Budget2" in order for the code to point to the correct sheet and work correctly. When I insert your code, the error goes away, but the string substitution does not happen.

Comment: Do you have the sheet name hard-coded in its code module?  You could use `Me.Name` to replace that.

Comment: Tim, your suggestion was in the ballpark and now it works, thanks.